# How to disable Cmd + [Num] in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, wordpress

I use WordPress keyboard shortcuts a lot, but Safari's use of Cmd + [Num] (e.g. 1, 2, 3) is overriding WordPress' use (which formats text with  tags).

How can I disable Safari's use of the keyboard shortcut so that I can use it for WordPress?

Answer (score 8):

The shortcuts are defined as the first few bookmarks in your Bookmarks Bar. You can see which bookmarks are defined by going to Bookmarks → Favorites Bar. Since they are menu items, you can disable them by remapping them to something else.

1. Open System Preferences → Keyboard → App Shortcuts.
2. Click the **+** to add a new shortcut.
3. Set the Application to Safari, the Menu Title to the exact name of one of your bookmarks, and the Keyboard Shortcut to something other than ⌘#.

   [image]
4. Repeat the process for the other bookmarks.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! What if I don't have any bookmarks in the favorites bar?

Comment: @Tom Then the keyboard shortcut should work fine without any need to remap it.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to be working regardless...presumably because the Menu Title is not being set correctly, despite me duplicating the bookmark names.

Comment: @Tom Are you writing the bookmark title as it is shown in the list at Bookmarks → Favorites Bar? [(example)](http://cl.ly/T86W)

Comment: Yep. Also, if there are no favorites in the bar, the shortcut still doesn't work.

Comment: This adds a new shortcut for that entry, but doesn't seem to remove the old old. So both Cmd-1 *and* Shift-Cmd-1 now opens the first favorite. (Very bad behavior on Safari's part; shortcuts should always exactly match to menu items.)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, my stupid fingers type CMD+2 instead of ALT+2, i notice that bookmarks automatically assigns this option and you can't disable it, BUT! the only way is to delete roots, on your favorite, the direct link is assigned to CMD+#, but if your favorite is inside a folder it doesn't get a #, so, you need to MOVE your direct shortcuts to a folder, then you'll lose the shortcut of evil! THAT RESOLVE MY ISSUE!!!