# Yosemite / Safari 8.0.8: reverting the keyboard shortcut for favorites

Tags: macos, safari, shortcut

I have been using the Safari shortcuts where you press CMD + (number) to access the links stored in your bookmarks bar (for example CMD + 1 = google CMD + 2 = Google Image search, CMD + 7 = Stack; etc), and since I updated to Yosemite yesterday, CMD + ... doesn't do anything anymore, and I have to grab the mouse while I'm working, aim the little arrow at the tiny little bookmark on top and click, and place my hand back on the keyboard to type my search (or other), and I find this to not only be counter-intuitive but also a waste of time and productivity.

If anyone knows a way to revert this so I can summon my bookmarks like a keyboard maestro again, I'm all ears!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the CMD + no. shortcuts are still functional. Perhaps there's some issue with your individual setup. Have you tried the keyboard shortcuts on another user account?

Comment: I'd like to know how you got that functionality in the first place (which I know ought to be another question;) https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19282 shows no such functionality, nor have I ever heard of it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/I4h1TmI766g
|
grgarside's answer here helped but I can only get it to work sometimes: 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115281/how-to-disable-cmd-num-in-safari

Comment: ahh... it only works if your Favourites are single bookmarks. Mine are all menus.

Comment: No if you have 1:menu1 and 2: single bookmark1 and 3: menu2 and 4: single bookmark2, the shortcut cmd + 1will take you to single bookmark1, the shortcut cmd +2 will take you to single bookmark2, etc. My 23 first bookmarks on the left of the bookmark bar are folders or menus but afterwards comes Google, Google Image, Facebook, Craigslist, etc, and the shortcuts send me to these single ones no problem "jumping" after the folders and menus.